# Simulate SNMP Trap with SNAT

Tags: iptables, nat, snmp

I have to test SNMP 2c Traps. I want to send those traps from some computer and the trap destination has iptables. So before the trap enters the NMS, I could just rewrite the real source of the trap to the desired source of the trap (an UPS).

example:

```
$IPTABLES -t nat -A PREROUTING -o em+  -p udp -m udp  -s 1.2.3.4   -d 10.1.2.3  --dport 162 -j SNAT --to-source 10.1.2.4
```

**Simulation computer: 1.2.3.4**

**NMS: 10.1.2.3**

**UPS: 10.1.2.4**

The problem is: The PREROUTING chain doesn't allow SNAT.
As far as I understand, I don't need to reply to that trap. I just have to receive the complete information packet. So I shouldn't need connection tracking.

Can anybody help me?

Thanks

Comment: Why not have it in the POSTROUTING chain in that case?

Comment: Because then, the NMS has no occasion to receive it: http://linux-ip.net/nf/nfk-traversal.png